# Verifying google pay purchase using Firebase CloudFunction

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, android-inapp-purchase

I've tried every other way to verify inapp purchase using cloud function...All are outdated(not supporting v3 api).

Is there a way to call a cloud function with all required information and verify if  the purchase was real and write to Firebase Firestore it's validity?

As per this [doc](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get),

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/products/productId/tokens/token
```

is supposed to be called by the server.

Comment: Any luck! I also require to verify the receipt at server side in Node.js using IABVerifier = require('iab_verifier');

Comment: I am working on Firebase Cloud Functions, working good, just this verify receipt issue, Always return false.